# Reporting online quiz results

Tags: javascript

Hello I am struggling to find the best approach to having a simple online quiz send the users results to a specified email. I am fairly new to Javascript, and if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jUbza/13/)

```
var allQuestions = [{question: "2 + 2", choices: ["4", "8", "10", "2"],     correctAnswer:0},
{question: "6 + 3", choices: ["7", "3", "5", "9"], correctAnswer:3},
{question: "4 + 4", choices: ["8", "7", "2", "9"],
correctAnswer:0},
{question: "5 + 0", choices: ["4", "5", "3", "9"], correctAnswer:1},];

//you can access checkbox name through an array
//match array number to number in allQuestions array

var questionNum = 0;
var scoreNum = 0;
var makeQuestions = "";


$(document).ready(function() {
    makeQuestions = function() {
        if(questionNum === allQuestions.length){
            $("input[value=SUBMIT]").remove();
            $("#questions").text(" Done!Please click the button below to submit your results.  Your score is" + " " + scoreNum);
        }
        else{
        $("#questions").text(allQuestions[questionNum].question);
        for(var i=0; i<allQuestions[questionNum]['choices'].length;i++){
            $('#words').append('<input type="radio" name="buttons">' + allQuestions[questionNum]['choices'][i] + '</input');
        }
        }
    }
    makeQuestions();

});



var checkQuestions = function() {
    var lenG = document.getElementsByName("buttons").length;
    console.log(lenG);
    var rightAnswer = allQuestions[questionNum]['correctAnswer'];
    for (var i=0; i<lenG; i++){
        if (document.getElementsByName("buttons")[i].checked === true) {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(document.getElementsByName("buttons")[i].checked);
            //compare value to what was inputted
            if(i === rightAnswer){
                scoreNum +=1;
                alert("Correct! Your score is" +" " + scoreNum);
            }
            else{
                alert("False! Your score is still"+ " " + scoreNum );
            }
        }

}
questionNum = questionNum +1;
$("#words").empty();
makeQuestions();

}
```

Comment: What's the specific problem with this code? (What error or unexpected behavior is occurring?)

Comment: No Error, I am just asking for a bit of guidance on how to have it report the "quiz" results to say a specified email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use a server-side language like PHP to mail the score to you.  You should also think of a way to attach some kind of user identifier (like a name) to each submission, otherwise you'll just get an inbox full of scores with no way to associate them with a quiz-taker.

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GbACX/2/) just to give you a basic idea of what to do.  I've put the contents of "submit.php" in the CSS box.  In case it doesn't resolve properly or something, here it is again:

```
<?php
$answers_correct = (ctype_digit($_POST['answers_correct']) ? $_POST['answers_correct'] : 'spoofed');

$to      = 'your@email.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'Answers correct: ' . $answers_correct;
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

Thank you for submitting your results!
```

Changes to your HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="questions"></div>
<div id="words"></div>

<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onClick="checkQuestions()" />

<div style="display:none;">
    <form id="answer_submission_form" action="submit.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="answers_correct" name="answers_correct">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
```

And changes to your JS, all inside the `$(document).ready(){...`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    makeQuestions = function() {
        if(questionNum === allQuestions.length){
            $("input[value=SUBMIT]").remove();
            $("#questions").text(" Done!Please click the button below to submit your results.  Your score is" + " " + scoreNum);
            $("#questions").append("<br><input type='button' id='submit_answers' value='SUBMIT'>");
            $("#answers_correct").val(scoreNum);
        }
        else{
            $("#questions").text(allQuestions[questionNum].question);
            for(var i=0; i<allQuestions[questionNum]['choices'].length;i++){
                $('#words').append('<input type="radio" name="buttons">' + allQuestions[questionNum]['choices'][i] + '</input');
            }
        }
    }
    makeQuestions();


    $('#submit_answers').on('click', function() {
        $('#answer_submission_form').submit();
    });

});
```

And if you really don't want to use a language like PHP, which I don't recommend, you could look into setting up a [form with a `mailto` action](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-email-form.phtml):

Comment: Thanks a million! This is exactly the advice I was looking for.Thanks for even building the fiddle, seeing it in front of me helps me a ton.

Comment: No prob, glad it helped!